# How does this filtering code use a function argument to fill the gap in the given computation?

Tags: javascript

So I am reading this book called "Eloquent JavaScript" and I came across the filter function for finding certain elements that pass the test.
Code is presented below:

```
filter(array, test) {
  let passed = [];
  for (let element of array) {
    // What exactly is test(element) in the if statement below?
    if (test(element)) {
      passed.push(element);
    }
  }
  return passed;
}

console.log(filter(SCRIPTS, script => script.living));
// → [{name: "Adlam", …}, …]
```

My question: What exactly is happening inside the scope of the `if` statement? It says in the book that `test` fills the "gap" in the computation. I can understand that it is being used as a return value from a function.  But why would you need a `element` inside of `test` if your `test` function is returning only `script.living`?

Also, if the answer is "because you are testing each element", how exactly is the test function "checking" the element?
I hope I made it clear in what I'm asking. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: The result of a `filter` predicate (such as `test` in the example)  is automatically evaluated for being either a) truthy or b) falsy https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/. In case of a) it's added to the array the filter function returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly is happening inside the scope of the if statement?

The `test` function is executed passing the `element` as parameter. This fact is also related with your next question

> why would you need an element inside of test if your test function is returning only script.living?

```js
script => script.living
```

`script` is just the name of the parameter. This name will be replaced with the actual element that the function receives when it's invoked. Therefore, when `if( test(element))` is executed, `script` gets bound to `element` and the actual instruction that gets executed is `element.living`.

So, for example, let's say that the current `element` is `{name: "Adlam", living: true}`. In this case, `test` function will return `true` because the element has a `living` property set to `true`.
On the other hand, if the element were `{name: John, living: false}`, `test` function would return `false` because `living` property is set to `false`.

### Going a little bit further

There are other things that are also happening here. Javascript has what are called `Falsy` and `Truthy` values:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/truthy

So in the examples above, the code inside the `if(test(element))` clause won't be executed if the `test(element)` function returns any possible `Falsy` value (`false`, `0`, `null`, `undefined`...). Example: `{name: "Adlam", living: null}`.
By contrary, the code inside the `if` clause will be executed if the `test(element)` function returns any of the `Truthy` values. Example: `{name: "Adlam", living: 1}`